# How to run new index automatic

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing

I have the dataframe

```
C_ID    P_ID    Text    Class   Code
1       Art     Kupo    1       1233
2       Art     Poxe    4       1934
3       Bop     Mome    2       453
4       Woo     Rax     1       9845
5       Art     Drop    3       2342
```

I want run create member_id based on P_ID (P_ID is the primary key by string type) because C_ID is not correct.

```
member_id   P_ID    Text    Class   Code
1           Art     Kupo    1       1233
1           Art     Poxe    4       1934
2           Bop     Mome    2       453
3           Woo     Rax     1       9845
4           Art     Drop    3       2342
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong you are trying to recreate your dataframe's index, you can do this by `df.set_index('colname')`. for further reference check **https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html**

Comment: it doesn't work because I need to convert P_ID (string primary key index) to member_id

Answer (score 0):

So you want unique member ids for each `P_ID`. This is a bit ugly, but I think it should do the trick:

```
df['member_id'] = df.P_ID.apply(lambda x: list(set(df.P_ID)).index(x))
```

(What is happening is first that we're turning the *series* P_ID into a *set* so as to remove duplicate values; we're then turning it into a *list* so that we can use the index of a value to give us a numerical id; we're then using this strategy to apply a lambda function to the P_ID column all at once to give us unique numerical `member_id`s for each unique P_ID).

---

I don't think you really want those to be an index as such for the dataframe, but if you did:

```
df.set_index('member_id')
```